# Artifactory 5.6.2 keep logging "db.properties with a timestamp later than the system's current time"

Tags: artifactory

Today I've upgraded the `Artifactory` from version `5.5.1` to `5.6.2` from `ZIP installation` by copying the following from old version to the new version directory

1. /etc
2. /access
3. /tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar

The `Artifactory` keep logging the following **forever**:-

```
2017-12-07 15:27:22,249 [Thread-5] [WARN ] (o.a.c.c.ConfigurationManagerImpl:352) - 
Detected a change on file /u01/app/artifactory-oss-5.6.2/etc/db.properties
with a timestamp later than the system's current time.  
The file's timestamp will be set as the current time.
...
Detected a change on file /u01/app/artifactory-oss-5.6.2/etc/artifactory.system.properties
with a timestamp later than the system's current time.  
The file's timestamp will be set as the current time.
...
Detected a change on file /u01/app/artifactory-oss-5.6.2/etc/mimetypes.xml
with a timestamp later than the system's current time.  
The file's timestamp will be set as the current time.
```

At the moment I've edited the `etc/logback.xml` to skip this logging as an interim solution.

```xml
<logger name="org.artifactory.common.config.ConfigurationManagerImpl" additivity="false">
    <level value="error" />
</logger>
```

I'm not sure If I'm doing something wrong or not. Could you please help to advice?

#### EDIT 1

Execute as @ajeans suggestion.

```sh
stat /u01/app/artifactory-oss-5.6.2/etc/db.properties
```

```
[root@aspg etc]# stat db.properties
  File: db.properties
  Size: 1799            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 1614303655  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0
Access: 2017-12-08 07:38:20.649419571 +0700
Modify: 2017-12-08 07:38:20.647419546 +0700
Change: 2017-12-08 07:38:20.647419546 +0700
 Birth: -
```

Comment: What are the access times on the files you carried over (etc/*)? A _stat_ should tell you if they are indeed living in the future.
So can you do _stat /u01/app/artifactory-oss-5.6.2/etc/db.properties_ and report back?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the `stat` execution result.

Comment: So were the dates given by the `stat` in the future compared to the result of `date` run on your machine?
Apparently, the code is looking for updates to those files to resolve them "live" and file timestamps in the future are dangerous for this feature.
The code that emits this warning is here: https://github.com/nuance-sspni/artifactory-oss/blob/af3fcf09e27cac836762e9957ad85bdaeec6e7f8/base/config/src/main/java/org/artifactory/common/config/wrappers/ConfigWrapperImpl.java#L347